# How to derive a function that depends on another function evaluated at different times

Tags: functions, derivatives, notation

I'm coming from physics, but I figured this is a mathematical question, so here I am. I have a scalar $f(\vec{x},\vec{y})$ that is a function of two different points $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ in space. My problem arises from the fact that this function is evaluated at different points of the same trajectory. That is, I have a particle following a path parametrized by $\vec{z}(t)$ and my function looks like

\begin{equation}
f\big[\vec{z}(t),\vec{z}(t')\big]
\end{equation}

This is not a problem on itself. The problem is that the function gets evaluated on these different points of the trajectory $\vec{z}(t)$ after I take the derivative respect to the first entry of the function. So I get something like

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) |_{\vec{x}=\vec{z}(t),\vec{y}=\vec{z}(t')}
\end{equation}

The first question is: Is there a source in the literature where this type of thing shows up?

The second question is: How would you notate that derivative? derivative respect to $\vec{z}$ doesn't work because it looks like it's acting on the second entry as well. **Is there some sort of notation for "Derive respect to whatever is in the first entry"?**

Comment: For scalar variables, this could be notated by $$f^{(0,0)}(x,y)=f(x,y),$$ $$f^{(1,0)}(x,y)=\frac\partial{\partial x}f(x,y),\quad f^{(0,1)}(x,y)=\frac\partial{\partial y}f(x,y),$$ $$f^{(2,0)}(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,y),\quad f^{(1,1)}(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}f(x,y),\quad f^{(0,2)}(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}f(x,y),$$ and so on. But I don't know about vector variables.

Comment: So in your case it could be written as $f^{(1,0)}(z(t),z(t'))$ if there's only one dimension.